# Load YouTube Performantly

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, asynchronous, youtube, freeze

The way YouTube recommends you load a video is like so:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zhawgd0REhA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

This loads the video as an iframe so they can detect iOS or other devices and deliver a swf or HTML5 player depending on what's necessary.

These snippets come from their Player API Demo. https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Unfortunately, in IE6-9 this causes serious slowdown - the browser seems to freeze up for as much as 5 seconds, even when the player is the only thing on the page and isn't set to autoplay. In addition, there's a touch of irony to this "demo" in that they aren't at all loading the player the way they recommend, and instead loading it via a custom written Google AppEngine/AppSpot app they put together - and it actually does load more performantly in the demo in IE than when one uses Google's recommended snippet.

Have others run into this? Is there a good solution?

Comment: If you know it's IE (which you can detect via user agent) you can use [SWFObject][1], which is the way they used to recommend doing it.


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: I see - that may be an elegant solution since it would still deliver an HTML5 player to iOS devices. I'll give this a go when I have some time for more testing.